# storing order in drag and drop interfaces

Tags: drag-and-drop

I guess this is less a direct problem but more of an implementation question.

For drag and drop interfaces. How do people store the order of the elements that are being re-arranged. Since a user expects the order to be preserved when the user refreshes the page, how do you store that kinda information in a relational database or other persistent layer?

A number system seems extraneous requiring multiple updates anytime anybody arranged anything and I couldn't think of a nicer system for storing that information especially if the user doesn't have to click "Done" or any other button after re-ordering. (IE Facebook Photos)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be a linked-list style: for each element, you store what is after it (or both before and after, for a doubly linked list).  This way, when you move something, you only have to update the affected elements.  Since you don't typically need to retrieve, say, the 2357th element (more typically you need to recreate the entire list) the performance impact should be fine.